# How do I make my mouse slower or faster?

Tags: performance, mouse

my last one got closed and I beleve it said to make a new thread but make more sence; so here it is: i've been looking up some ways to slow your mouse down for this game, but what they do is not relateing to my computer. what im asking is if any of you own a laptop and know how to slow the mouse down, please tell me. is this clear enough?

Comment: If your question was closed as "not a real question", please edit it so that it is easier to understand and request a re-open.  Use proper sentences and provide as much detail as you can for the question to be answered.   This is not a forum, and this is not a thread.  It is a question that should be written in a way that it can be answered.  Please do not duplicate questions.

Comment: understood; making sure that this is clear enough and trying to make sure like im not just wasting my time here...

Comment: Including things like the OS you're using and what you've tried already might help keep your questions from getting closed.

Comment: please don't repost, [edit your previous question to add in details](http://superuser.com/posts/608267/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the speed of the mouse is related to it's dpi
there is a way to slow down or speed up the mouse for windows

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (in the text box type "control" and press OK)
2. Go to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound
3. Then under Devices and Printers you see "Mouse" click on it
4. On the Mouse properties you go to "Pointer Options" tab
5. Then you will see select a pointer speed

but it might not work with games as the game it self manages the mouse movements.

Comment: when I press win (ctrl) + R nothing happens. and no, the game is 'take something literally' a game where you have to do stuff like this.

Comment: No you got to press Win + R http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key

Comment: there is no win key

Comment: Are you sure you don't have it on your keyboard?

Comment: @helpplz just open Control Panel